# jquery dialog jumps when page scrolled (jquery-ui 1.10.3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, opera

**EDIT:
Having just tested it in more browsers, it happens in Opera, IE 9 and Firefox as well.
It seems to work fine in sites like jsbin, jsfiddle, etc... but if you just create a HTML file with that code and run it in the browser, then the problem happens.**

Basically given the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page is scrolled to the top, the dialog will work fine. But the further you scroll down the page, when you then try to move the dialog using the handle, it jumps down the page by about the same amount that you have scrolled.

Comment: In which version did this problem occur? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/rTwqN/) it seems behave the same (tested it in Chrome, Firefox, Opera - each latest version)

Comment: I'm in version 12.14 Strange thing is it works fine in jsfiddle/jsbin, etc... but if I just copy that code into an HTML file and load that up in the browser, that's when the issue occurs

Comment: I've just edited the question, as it is happening in lots of browsers actually

Comment: Yes just tested it in a plain `.html` file and it happened in FF etc.

Answer (score 2):

The bug seems to have been introduced in jQuery ui 1.10.3.  When I switched back to 1.10.2, the dialog acted normal.

A ticket was opened a few weeks ago:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315